# Another way to handle a common JQuery event handling pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I have the following code for example

```
$("a.foo").bind(function (e){
    var t;
    if ( $(e.target).is("a") ){
        t = $(e.target);
    }else{
        t = $(e.target).parent("a");

    }
    var data = t.attr("data-info");

});
```

In english. I might have a list of anchors within which there may be
a number of spans. Each anchor is declared as

```
<a class="foo" href="#" data-info="1">
    <span> ... </span>
    <span> ... </span>
</a>

<a class="foo" href="#" data-info="2">
    <span> ... </span>
    <span> ... </span>
</a>
...
...
```

I bind a handler to the click event of the anchor
but the event object comes back with the anchor OR one of the spans
depending on where I click. So to get my html5 "data-info" value into
the callback I have to insert a bit of messy code. This is now appearing
throughout my code to the point where I am guessing there might be an
idiomatic JQuery way of handling this.

EDIT: Backbone snippet showing my real problem ( excuse the coffeescript )

```
class DashboardView extends Backbone.View

  events:
    "click a.foo": "editLogItem"

  editLogItem: (e)->
    t = $(e.target).closest("a")
```

Comment: I may have just answered my own question. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Yes, that's a useful function, but in this case you don't need it at all.

Comment: You don't `bind` it to the click event (ok maybe it binds to all events) You are missing `click`: `$("a.foo").bind('click', function (e){`. Your HTML is also wrong, it should be `class = "foo"` and not `class = ".foo"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TYgdX/4/)

`$(this)` will get the element defined by the selector you bind too.

```
$("a.foo").click(function (e){
    var data = $(this).data("info");
});
```

You should also use `.data` rather then `.attr("data-...")`

**Edit:**

If `this` is overwritten you can use `e.currentTarget` which will have the same value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("a.foo").bind('click', function (e){` ?

Comment: @FelixKling probably. I believe `.bind` is overloaded to bind to all events.

Comment: If it is they should document that... i don't/didn't know.

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't seem to be. I checked the source. I changed it to `.click`, thanks!

Comment: I see where I bit myself. I'm actually using coffeescript/backbone and my code is slightly different to the above. The answer above is correct for the question I posed.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing update your question with the backbone snippet, I'll look into a way of handling it.

Comment: @Raynos The snippet is added. It is likely to be a coffeescript problem as coffeescript binds the callback to the object not to the DOM element. I don't think there is a way to do other than I have done in the code.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I believe `e.currentTarget` should solve your problem for `.bind`. I don't know how to handle `.delegate` which backbone also does automatically for you in some cases. Btw it's _backbone_ that binds it to the object, not coffeescript itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the handler is attached to the `<a>` anyway, that'll always be `this` in the handler, so it doesn't matter what the target was.

```
$("a.foo").click(function (e){
    var data = $(this).data('info');

    // ...    
});
```

Note also that to get the value of "data-xxx" attributes you can use the ".data()" function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("a.foo").bind('click', function (e){` ?

Comment: Oops yes sorry - I c/p'd from the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.foo').click(function () {
    var data = $(this).data('info');
});
```

I'm using the click handler because you specifically mention catching the click event.

Comment: No reason to use ".attr()" to get a "data-" value - use ".data()" instead.